# I want to get a pop up window when I click a button.that pop window should consists of a label name.OK button CLOSE button

Tags: java, jbutton, joptionpane

I want a pop up window when I pressed a button.Can anyon helo me with  the right code.Here is my code.Iam new to java swings.Thank you in advance.here is my code.

```
            JButton testButton=new JButton("test");
                    toolBar.addComponentRight(testButton);
                    testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
    here I want to replace code-------- 
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you clicked me");

                        }
                    });

        Here in output pop up window  I am getting only OK button.I need CANCEL button also along with OK button.Can anyone suggest me with the right code.Thank you in advance.
```

Comment: I did not reach 15 reputation points so Iam unable to vote your answer I tried though.

Comment: Yes! Vishal Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I got the code.I hope it would be useful.here is my modified code.Thank you vishal.


     JButton testButton=new JButton("test");
                        toolBar.addComponentRight(testButton);
                        testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                            {


           JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((Component) null, "Do you want to close ?", "Window Title", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do something likewise,**

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((Component) null, "Do you want to close ?", "Window Title", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

It will display likewise,

[image]